# Execution of two mysql queries gets extremely slow

Tags: mysql, performance, loops, execution-time

I've made a php-script which exactly does what I want, but it's extremely slow on the server. When I'm testing it locally, runtime is about 60-80 ms for the whole script. When I run it on my webserver it takes about 4 seconds. But I can't get clear what the problem on the webserver is.

When commenting out soms parts of my script, I can locate the problem to the second query within a while loop. When I don't execute the second query, the execution time is brought back to about 60ms. But the strangest thing about is, is that the while-loop is limited to only 8 results and an example of the query gives in phpmyadmin on the webserver an execution time of less than 1 ms. So I'm confused that 60ms + 8* 1 ms can get to a total of 4 seconds. So I think there must be something else which is slowing down the script, but I can't get clear what that is. I hope that somebody can give me a clue, where to look.

The first part with query 1 (max 8 results):

```
$sql = "
SELECT W.*
     , P.weektaak
     , P.extra
     , P.toets
     , P.toets2
     , P.toetsdag
     , P.toetsdag2
     , P.toetssoort 
  FROM weken W
  LEFT 
  JOIN planner P 
    ON P.weekid = W.id 
   AND P.vakid = ? 
   AND P.studieid = ?
 WHERE W.id >= ? 
 ORDER 
    BY W.id 
 LIMIT 8";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $checkrow['vakid'], $checkrow['studieid'], $_SESSION['weekid']);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

if ($res->num_rows >= 1) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
```

The second part with query 2 (which gets repeated at a max of 8 times):

```
$toetssql = "SELECT S.leerjaar, S.studie, V.afkorting, P.toets, P.toets2, P.toetsdag, P.toetsdag2, P.toetssoort FROM vakkenkoppeling K
             LEFT JOIN planner P ON P.studieid = K.studieid AND P.vakid = K.vakid AND P.weekid = ?
             LEFT JOIN studie S ON K.studieid = S.id
             LEFT JOIN vakken V ON K.vakid = V.id
             WHERE S.leerjaar = ? AND S.studie = ? AND (P.toets != '' OR P.toets2 != '')
             ORDER BY P.toetsdag";
                            
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($toetssql); 
$stmt2->bind_param('sss', $row['id'], $checkrow['leerjaar'], $checkrow['studie']); 
$stmt2->execute(); 
$toetsres = $stmt2->get_result(); 
$stmt2->close();

if ($toetsres->num_rows >= 1) {
    while ($toetsrow = $toetsres->fetch_assoc()) {
```

I already read that it's recommended to leave queries out of loops, but I can't imagine how I can do it in this script. And besides that I've used queries within loops before, but never experienced this kind of slowness.

Thanks in advance for any clues that can help me.

--- EDIT 07/19

I think both reactions already pushed me into the right direction in solving this problem. So I'm going to look into indexes right now, but I'll post the results of EXPLAIN here first:

Query 1

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys key     key_len ref  row  Extra
1  SIMPLE      W     range PRIMARY       PRIMARY 4       NULL 53   Using index condition
1  SIMPLE      P     ALL   NULL          NULL    NULL    NULL 6421 Using where
```

Query 2

````
id select_type table type   possible_keys key     key_len ref                                 rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      K     ALL    NULL          NULL    NULL    NULL                                233  Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      S     eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY 4       plannersagnieten_planner.K.studieid 1    Using where
1  SIMPLE      V     eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY 4       plannersagnieten_planner.K.vakid    1
1  SIMPLE      P     ALL    NULL          NULL    NULL    NULL                                6421 Using where```
````

Comment: When you run it locally, are you running it against the production database or just against your test version of the database? Can you try running an `EXPLAIN` on the query on production and providing the output? My first thought that is you're lacking an index somewhere and so your query is doing a table scan.

Comment: @DavidTran I was indeed lacking the right indexes on my tables. Execution time dropped to 40-80 ms. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    LEFT JOIN  planner P  ON P.weekid = W.id
      AND  P.vakid = ?
      AND  P.studieid = ?
```

and

```
    LEFT JOIN  planner P  ON P.studieid = K.studieid
      AND  P.vakid = K.vakid
      AND  P.weekid = ?
```

both need `INDEX(weekid, valid, studieid)` (in any order)

```
    LEFT JOIN  studie S  ON K.studieid = S.id
    LEFT JOIN  vakken V  ON K.vakid = V.id
    WHERE  S.leerjaar = ?
      AND  S.studie = ?
```

is not a "LEFT" join since you specify values for 2 columns.  I suggest adding `INDEX(leerjaar, studie, id)`

```
    AND  (P.toets != '' OR  P.toets2 != '' )
```

In general, `OR` cannot be optimized.  But please provide the `EXPLAIN`.

```
    ORDER BY  P.toetsdag
```

might benefit from `INDEX(toetsdag)`

Why do you need to run the query 8 times?

Comment: Perfect! I added your suggestions and looked into some other tables where I didn't manage the indexes and without any other changes the execution time dropped to 40-80 ms for the whole script! Thanks for your help!